# Реализация long polling средствами pure javascript и ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Доброго дня! Подскажите, пожалуйста примеры использования javascript для организации long polling. Приведите свои комментарии. Пока не очень понятно, что это такое, чтобы реализовать самостоятельно. В гугле тоже маловато информации. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, идея же просто в том, чтобы периодически обращаться на сервер по определенному тайм ауту и смотреть, не появилось ли чего то нового. На клиентской стороне возможно сделать скрипт, который с помощью **ajax** забирает данные с определенного метода.

Проще это сделать используя библиотеку **jQuery**, поскольку там удобно обернуты асинхронные вызовы в функцию [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

View может выглядеть так (**Не забудь добавить скрипты для jQuery, по умолчанию в MVC проекте они есть**):

```
<div id="messages">
    <div class="msg old">
        Тут можно подгрузить старые сообщения, при первой загрузке страницы
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
//Функция, которая будет добавлять сообщения на страницу, полученные с сервера
function addmsg(type, msg){
    $("#messages").append(
        "<div class='msg "+ type +"'>"+ msg +"</div>"
    );
}

function waitForMsg(){
    /* Запрос к /Home/YourAction */
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("YourAction","Home")",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 15000, /* Тайм аут обращения (как раз нужно для организации пуллинга) */
        success: function(data){ /* Будет вызвано, если метод будет обработан верно */
            addmsg("new", data); /* Добавление ответа с сервера */
            waitForMsg(); //Опять пошлем на сервер долгоиграющий запрос
        },
        //Будет вызвано, если возникнет ошибка
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            addmsg("error", textStatus + " (" + errorThrown + ")");
            setTimeout(
                waitForMsg, /* Попробовать еще раз */
                15000); /* Через 15 секунд */
        }
    });
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    waitForMsg(); /* Старт опроса сервера */
});
</script>
```

Соответственно, чтобы это работало необходимо на сервере создать метод, с которого будем брать сообщения.

**UPDATE:** после обсуждения в комментариях, стало ясно, что необходимо на сервере реализовать асинхронный возврат результата с сервера.

Для этого я предлагаю для примера создать заглушку, содержащую сообщения и метод, возвращающий одно непрочитанное сообщение:

```
public class Message
{
    public bool IsReaded { get; set; }
    public string MessageString { get; set; }
}

public static class MessagesDB
{
    public static List<Message> messages = new List<Message>()
    {
        new Message { IsReaded = false , MessageString = "Сообщение 1"},
        new Message { IsReaded = false , MessageString = "Сообщение 2"},
        new Message { IsReaded = false , MessageString = "Сообщение 3"},
        new Message { IsReaded = false , MessageString = "Сообщение 4"},
        new Message { IsReaded = false , MessageString = "Сообщение 5"},
    };

    public static async Task<string> GetIsNotReadedMessage()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000); //Чтобы показать, что сообщения могут приходить не сразу

        var isNotReadedMessage = messages.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.IsReaded);
        if (isNotReadedMessage != null)
        {
            isNotReadedMessage.IsReaded = true;
            return isNotReadedMessage.MessageString;
        }
        else
            return "Нет новых сообщений";
    }
}
```

Пример метода, который возвращает одно сообщение:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> YourAction()
{
    var message = await MessagesDB.GetIsNotReadedMessage();
    return Json(message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //Эта строчка нужна, если мы хотим обращаться через GET за json.
}
```

Все. Еще раз суть. После загрузки страницы у тебя js асинхронно вызывает метод на сервере, который ждет, когда вернется сообщение из заглушки и возвращает строку сообщения и после удачного получения такой строки, добавляет еще один `div` с сообщением.

Для наглядности я сделал [пример в .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wpQAAP), его можно посмотреть в действии. ***К сожалению в этой песочнице, видимо, не совсем корректно работает статические методы, поэтому он всегда выводит первое сообщение***. При запуске проекта в Visual Studio все работает, как ожидается.

Comment: ну вообще говоря - это не _long_ polling

Comment: @Grundy что ты имеешь в виду?

Comment: *long pooling* - это вполне конкретная технология, которая построена на запросах с длинными тайм-аутами (сколько браузер позволит)

Comment: то, что это не _long_ polling. Здесь запрос не висит на сервере ожидая какого-то события, а сразу получает что ничего не произошло и возвращает ответ, и только потом ждет указанный интервал

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен. Но тогда и правда проще использовать SignalR, как Andrew Takker написал

Comment: @teovankot, либо подправить вашу серверную часть

Comment: @PavelMayorov почитал, посмотрел, поправил, вы это имеете в виду говоря о long polling?

Comment: @Grundy поправил ответ, верно ли теперь? Или я опять что то упускаю?

Comment: Вот только правильная реализация `GetIsNotReadedMessage()` тут не показана. В реальности ведь так просто 3 секунды ждать нет смысла - надо ждать именно самого момента появления нового сообщения. А это самое сложное.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Согласен, но она будет сильно зависеть от того, где именно будут храниться сообщения. А этой информации у меня нет.

Comment: Когда речь идет о long pooling, сообщения обычно не "хранятся", а передаются от одного клиента к другому.

Comment: @PavelMayorov не могу согласиться, вопрос хранения - отдельно от пуллинга. Лог пуллинг предполагает длительное ожидание ответа от сервера клиентом. И нет описания того как именно их хранить. А вот для исчерпывающего описания метода необходимо знать, где храним.

Comment: Да, но для того чтобы лонг пуллинг имел смысл - на стороне сервера должен быть какой-то эффективный способ получения события вовремя, отличный от активного ожидания. Или очередь сообщений - или событие должно появиться в результате обработки запроса от другого клиента.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну, тогда нам остается только ждать, когда тот кто вопрос задал прояснит условия задачи

Comment: Можете привести точное описание того, как в теории устроен лонг пуллинг? В интернете слишком сжатое определение.

Comment: Ну вообще @PavelMayorov показал теорию. Как будет внутри - это завист от вашего сценария и выбранного вида хранения данных на сервере.

Answer (score 2):

Вместе с ASP.NET MVC можно использовать [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)  для организации лонгполлинга или сокет соединений.

Comment: Я знаю про SignalR и другие библиотеки. Но я хотел бы реализовать собственноручно.

Answer (score -1):

В ASP.NET MVC есть чудесная возможность - асинхронные контроллеры.

С их помощью long pooling в ASP.NET MVC делается примерно так:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> WaitForMessage() {
  var tcs = new TaskComplectionSource<MyMessage>();
  var token = Responce.ClientDisconnectedToken;

  using (token.Register(() => { CancelWaitForMessage(...); tcs.TrySetCanceled(); })) {
      BeginWaitForMessage(..., msg => tcs.TrySetResult(msg));
  }
  var msg = await tcs.Task;

  return Json(msg);
}
```

Методы BeginWaitForMessage и CancelWaitForMessage реализуют логику ожидания сообщения, вам их придется написать самостоятельно. Например, там может быть подписка на событие и отписка от события.

В ASP.NET Core все немного проще - токен отмены можно получить как параметр:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> WaitForMessage(CancellationToken token) { ...
```

На стороне клиента long poling-запросы будут выглядеть так же, как и обычные запросы.